# GTLDriveFile icon size

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Is it possible to retrieve icons for google drive files that are of a size I nominate? The purpose would be to match the size of icons we are using for local files and other files. If not, I guess we'll scale them ourselves.

[image]

Comment: Are you askingg about IMAGE (jpg, png) icons?

Comment: No. I am referring to 

    `GTLDriveFile -iconLink`

I have added an image to illustrate. I'm referring to the icons attached to the file names.

Comment: GTLDriveFile is IOS specific I guess. Is there an  'ios drive sdk' tag you can use? [google-drive-sdk] usually refers to the [REST Api](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) (this API is lower level, sits under IOS api).

Comment: I guess not, but I can double check. I used the tag linked from the iOS API documentation pages. Anyway, I also added an iOS tag.

Comment: Sorry, the reason I bugged you was that I was solving this thing for Android with image icons and REST api [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472349/google-drive-android-api-requested-dimension-image-download/28481619#28481619), so I thought it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like multiple sizes are available at this google [setup and deployment page](http://setup.googleapps.com/Home/user-resources/google-icons-and-logos).